# Are both getters and setters mandatory in JSF's managed beans?

Tags: java, jsf, managed-bean

I have a JSF component which is initialized from a managed bean's getter `getProperty()`. Is it mandatory to also have a setter `setProperty()` in that managed bean?

Comment: Is this for use with the binding attribute?

Comment: the component's value is computed on the run. I don't have an attribute property in MB for getProperty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends.

Some property bindings must be read-write. For example, if you bind the value of a component that implements [`EditableValueHolder`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/faces/component/EditableValueHolder.html). Other properties can be read-only.

If you use the `binding` attribute for dynamically creating component instances, this must also be read-write as per the contract defined in the specification.

Comment: value is linked with value attribute on component. Component is f:param so is not editable, I not use binding to link value on component so I think it's correct without setter.

Answer (score 1):

No, not mandatory. Unless you want to be able to bind the property in a way that allows its value to be changed.

EG. If you have a list of objects you want to display in a data table then a setter may not be needed. If you bind a string property to an textInput then you will need a setter.