# PropertyNotFoundException in SelectBooleanCheckbox

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I have one checkbox per each node in `TreeNode` component of PrimeFaces 3.3.1 which is throwing a `javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException` inside its `value` attribute. Here's my code:

```
<p:tree value="#{CadBean.treeNode}" var="rec">  
<p:treeNode>
    <h:outputText value="#{rec.codigo}" />
</p:treeNode>

<p:treeNode type="Funcionality" icon="ui-icon16-weblibrary-folderopened">
    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{CadBean.alreadyAssociated(rec.id)}">
        <p:ajax event="click" listener="#{CadBean.onrecClicked(rec.id)}" />
    </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
    <h:outputText value="#{rec.codigo}" />
</p:treeNode>

<p:treeNode type="Page" icon="ui-icon16-weblibrary-htmlpage">
    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{CadBean.alreadyAssociated(rec.id)}">
        <p:ajax event="click" listener="#{CadBean.onrecClicked(rec.id)}" />
    </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
    <h:outputText value="#{rec.codigo}" />
</p:treeNode>

<p:treeNode type="System" icon="ui-icon16-weblibrary-computer">
    <h:outputText value="#{rec}" />
</p:treeNode>
```

The exception is thrown in `value="#{CadBean.alreadyAssociated(rec.id)}"`.

The boolean method is like this:

```
public boolean alreadyAssociated(int recId) {
for (Association a : associations) {
    if (a.getRec().getId() == recId) {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
}
```

And here's the exception:

```
SEVERE: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /s_ca/cadRec.xhtml @54,122 value="#{CadBean.alreadyAssociated(rec.id)}": Property 'alreadyAssociated' not found on type br.com.tsg.web.beans.CadBean
```

I'm using Mojarra 2.1.9 and can't use `selectionMode="checkbox"` in the TreeNode because I'll need two more components with the checkbox.

Thanks.

Comment: Which server are you using?

Comment: value="#{CadBean.alreadyAssociated(rec.id)}", so if you submit,where variable will be stored ?

Comment: Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580167/are-both-getters-and-setters-mandatory-in-jsfs-managed-beans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I just had to create a method like this:

```
public void setAlreadyAssociated(boolean b) {
}
```

Yeah, it's a bad workaround... but solved.